Suggested edit reviewer stats are not formatted properly
Under Reviewer Stats, it says [Username] has [number] edit suggestions approved, [number] edit suggestions rejected, and [number] edit suggestions improved.
Example image:

That sounds like the reviewer has made a number of edit suggestions, and they have been approved.
Rather, it should be [Username] has approved [number] edit suggestions, rejected [number] edit suggestions, and improved [number] edit suggestions.

It certainly used to be correct at one time

Yes, @RobertLongson, I think it changed recently

@J.W.Tanner is correct, most likely this happened in July 1st this year when something else was fixed. :/

Letting you know this got tagged as planned just now, as tag-only edits don't trigger notifications.

The fix for this is done and should be on production soon.

@Berthold it's generally desirable to post an answer instead of just adding the completed tag and leaving a comment. Even if you don't elaborate much, if anything, an answer fits the Q&A better because it can be accepted.

presumably this is on https://math.stackexchange.com

This was not just on math stack exchange

The fix for this is done and should be on production soon.

Is there a build planned for today? I noticed the site's still running yesterday's build.

It seems to be corrected now
